# Meaning of testing 'addEventListener' in htmlElement

Tags: javascript, events, addeventlistener

What is the purpose of testing the following condition?

```
if ('addEventListener' in htmlElement) {
  // do sth
}
```

I have seen that in some code examples of event emitter constructors. I first thought it was to test whether an event was bound to a HTML element but it turns out the condition also returns `true` for HTML elements with no events attached to them.

Edit:

Here's a real life [example](https://github.com/Splidejs/splide/blob/514a2ccff2cb1a6b1ca70e24b6928b4e109a687c/dist/js/splide.js#L347) to give a bit more context.

Comment: We can't tell you why the person who wrote that code choose to do that. I could speculate, but it would just be my opinion.

Comment: I added a link to a real life example to give more context.

Answer (score -1):

This code checks whether the `addEventListener` property is available. The method `addEventListener` is a part of EventTarget interface. All DOM elements should have it, I think.

Comment: So what's the point of checking if `addEventListener` is available if all DOM elements have it?

Comment: While everything you say here is true, that just puts you in the same position as the OP, wondering why the code shown checks what should be a certainty. This isn't an answer to that question (indeed I don't think it's possible to answer the question without a lot more information).